# Positioning a formula in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, position

I want to be able to add this formula into my tkinter window and then position this whole thing like that into the bottom center of the window. Inside the window I also have a canvas above it that I .pack() in.

My code looks something like this right now

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1200, height=525)
canvas.pack()

text1 = Label(root, text= "P(H|E)=")
text2 = Label(root, text= "SAA + (")
text3 = Label(root, text= "+ [0.34])")
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)
entry3 = Entry(root)

text1.pack()
entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
text2.pack()
entry3.pack()
text3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read the docs on the Tkinter geometry managers? You can do this with [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) (possibly with some extra subframes), but it may be easier to do with [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). But you'll need to read the docs and go through an example or two to get an idea of what you can do with the geometry managers and how, and then you'll be able to write something that at least gets you close; without doing that, you won't be able to understand (and therefore maintain, extend, or even debug) any answers you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break down what you want into neat rows and columns. Then make a Frame for each subunit, and put them together the way you need them.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

leftside = tk.Frame(root)
lbl = tk.Label(leftside, text= "P(H|E)=")
lbl.pack(anchor='c')
leftside.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

rightside = tk.Frame(root)

numerator = tk.Frame(rightside)
entry1 = tk.Entry(numerator, width=5)
entry1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
lbl = tk.Label(numerator, text='+')
lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
entry2 = tk.Entry(numerator, width=5)
entry2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
numerator.pack()

division_bar = tk.Frame(rightside, bg='black', height=4)
division_bar.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)

denominator = tk.Frame(rightside)
text2 = tk.Label(denominator, text= "SAA + (")
text2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
entry3 = tk.Entry(denominator, width=5)
entry3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
text3 = tk.Label(denominator, text= "+ [0.34])")
text3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
denominator.pack()

rightside.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```